# How to insert smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, smalldatetime

I'm new to sql server since this is the requirement of my client. I can't insert because of the error I'm getting regarding the smalldatatime. What's wrong with my query? I have tried everything but still it gives me error.

Here are the things I tried:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON
INSERT INTO table1
(id, timelog) values
(1, 2018-07-24 06:30:50.000)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 OFF
```

ERROR I GOT:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '06'.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON
INSERT INTO table1
(id, timelog) values
(1, '2018-07-24 06:30:50.000')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 OFF
```

ERROR I GOT:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON
INSERT INTO table1
(id, timelog) values
(1, 2018-07-24T06:30:50.000)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 OFF
```

ERROR I GOT:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'T06:'

Comment: What's the structure of `table1`? Your second approach is correct but it seems you're trying to insert a date on an int column

Comment: Here: 

CREATE TABLE table1(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    timelog smalldatetime NOT NULL
);

Comment: What's the correct way to insert smalldatetime or datetime?

Comment: Syntax error, Inserting values in to tables: INSERT INTO table1 (id, timelog)
Values (1, '2018-07-24 00:05:44.610')

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is the 2nd, but you are missing the `VALUES` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE table1( id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, timelog smalldatetime NOT NULL ); 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON
INSERT INTO table1
(id, timelog) values
(1, '2018-07-24 06:30:50.000')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 OFF

select * from table1
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: but i'm still getting the same error "Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date"

Comment: @irish The syntax is correct, see the fiddle [here](http://rextester.com/JWOE35627)